# Firebase CLI giving segmentation fault on Ubuntu

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-tools

I'm having a hard time with firebase CLI,when I install it with npm, either locally in a projet or globally, and I call the command `firebase` it gives `Segmentation fault` with no further details.

I firs thought that the problem was with my version of Node since I was using 9.x, I moved back to 8.x versions, and reinstalled firebase with no success, I upgraded to 12.x, with no success too always same error.

I'm using NVM to handle my node versions properly, but still I can't find a fix for this problem.

nvm list gives this :

```
 ->      v8.11.3
        v8.13.0
        v12.3.0
         system
```

When I run `npm list firebase-tools` it gives `firebase-tools@7.9.0`, I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling with no success .